# SQL update from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a seemingly basic SQL update to perform on a postgreSQL table that takes values from another table, the table structures are as follows...

**sessions_table**

session_id (PK)
velocity
time

**lengths_table**

length_id
session_id
length_dist

I want to update the `velocity` field with the sum of the `length_dist` values where `session_table.session_id = lengths_table.session_id`

I am trying the following statement but get `ERROR: null value in column "velocity" violates not-null constraint` when I run it (it works fine when I specify a single row)

```
UPDATE sessions_table 
SET velocity = ROUND((SELECT SUM(lengths_table.length_dist) 
                      FROM lengths_table
                      WHERE lengths_table.session_id = sessions_table.session_id)/time,2)
```

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Thanks

David

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if it is a typing mistake or not. In your query above, you have `SELECT SUM(lengths_table.length_dist) FROM lengths`. Shouldn't it be `FROM lengths_table`.

Comment: ah yes, just a typo, will change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

Your syntax is wrong (there is no lengths_table). Should be:

```
UPDATE sessions_table 
SET velocity = ROUND((SELECT SUM(lengths.length_dist) 
                      FROM lengths_table 
                      WHERE lengths.session_id = sessions_table.session_id)/time,2)
```

or, there are some cases where a sessions_table record has no macthing record in lengths_table. So you need to set `velocity` to zero in this case to satisfy your non-null constraint:

```
UPDATE sessions_table 
SET velocity = coalesce(ROUND((SELECT SUM(lengths_table.length_dist) 
                               FROM lengths 
                               WHERE lengths_table.session_id = sessions_table.session_id)/time,2),0)
```

or, there are some matching records in the lengths_table with null values in length_dist, so you need to replace those with zero for the sum to work:

```
UPDATE sessions_table 
SET velocity = ROUND((SELECT SUM(coalesce(lengths_table.length_dist,0)) 
                      FROM lengths_table 
                      WHERE lengths_table.session_id = sessions_table.session_id)/time,2)
```